# Implementing Tree Using C++ Templates

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism

I am trying to learn how templates in C++ work so I would like to implement a tree using C++ templates.  Here is a traditional polymorphic version:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
    virtual ~Node() {}
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class InnerNode : public Node {
public:
    InnerNode(Node *lhs, Node *rhs) {
        m_lhs = lhs;
        m_rhs = rhs;
    }

    virtual ~InnerNode() {
        delete m_lhs;
        delete m_rhs;
    }

    virtual void print() {
        cout << "inner" << endl;
        if (m_lhs != NULL)
            m_lhs->print();
        if (m_rhs != NULL)
            m_rhs->print();
    }
private:
    Node *m_lhs;
    Node *m_rhs;
};

class LeafNode : public Node {
    virtual void print() {
        cout << "leaf" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Node *l1 = new LeafNode();
    Node *l2 = new LeafNode();
    Node *r = new InnerNode(l1, l2);
    r->print();
}
```

I am trying to implement a version of this code using only templates but I'm having some trouble with something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Node {
public:
    virtual ~Node() {}
    void print() {
        static_cast<T *>(this)->print();
    }
};

class InnerNode : public Node<InnerNode> {
public:
    InnerNode(Node *lhs, Node *rhs) {
        m_lhs = lhs;
        m_rhs = rhs;
    }

    virtual ~InnerNode() {
        delete m_lhs;
        delete m_rhs;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "inner" << endl;
        if (m_lhs != NULL)
            m_lhs->print();
        if (m_rhs != NULL)
            m_rhs->print();
    }
private:
    Node *m_lhs;
    Node *m_rhs;
};

class LeafNode : public Node<LeafNode> {
    virtual void print() {
        cout << "leaf" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    Node *l1 = new LeafNode();
    Node *l2 = new LeafNode();
    Node *r = new InnerNode(l1, l2);
    r->print();
}
```

How can I adapt the polymorphic version to use templates instead?

Comment: Why are `InnerNode` and `LeafNode` different types? I'd expect the only usage of the template to be the data type that the node is holding.

Comment: Scala and other functional languages tend to use two types for Inner & Leaf nodes.

Comment: I realize that - I'm only suggesting why the questioner may have used that paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

Templates allow you to replace a type with a name and generate specific instances of the code using that type.  For example, it's possible to have nodes with variant types.

Your Node<> template never refers to the template type parameter, so there is no reason to make it a template.  In essence your "Node" class is just an abstract interface, not a template.  InnerNode also doesn't need to be a template because there are no varying types since you can just store the base class pointer to the leaves.

The leaves have the data and therefore are candidates for being templatized, but as your example puts no data in the leaf nodes the application of the template type is not apparent.

Hopefully this will illustrate:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// interface for interacting with general nodes
class INode {
public:
    virtual ~INode() {}
    virtual void print() = 0;
};

class InnerNode : public INode {

public:
    InnerNode(INode *lhs, INode *rhs) {
        m_lhs = lhs;
        m_rhs = rhs;
    }

    virtual ~InnerNode() {
        delete m_lhs;
        delete m_rhs;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << "inner" << endl;
        if (m_lhs != NULL)
            m_lhs->print();
        if (m_rhs != NULL)
            m_rhs->print();
    }
private:
    INode *m_lhs;
    INode *m_rhs;
};

template< typename DataType >
class LeafNode : public INode {
    virtual ~LeafNode() {};
    public:
    LeafNode(DataType data) : m_data(data) {}

    virtual void print() {
        cout << "leaf:" << endl;
        cout << m_data << endl;
    }
    private:
    DataType m_data;
};

int main() {
    INode *l1 = new LeafNode<int>(2);
    INode *l2 = new LeafNode<float>(3.14);
    INode *r = new InnerNode(l1, l2);
    r->print();
    delete r;
}
```

http://cpp.sh/3rmq

Answer (score -1):

Your question pre-supposes that a tree is a data structure which holds data.  That data is the type that the template will handle.  If you don't have any data, then you don't have a datatype to generalize (template).

Since you asked about templates, let me just assume you have a tree, which keeps track of "some data type" which we'll call myDataType.  Suppose it is a string.  Here's an absolutely minimal tree interface, and none of the implementation details.  I know it's a pretty useless tree, but the question was about templates.

```
typedef myData std::string;

class tree {
private:
    struct node {
        myData data;
        node * left, right;
    };
    node * head;
public:
    void add (myData value);
    bool is_value_in_the_tree (const myData &value);
};
```

If you use different node types for inner and leaf nodes, that's no problem.  That's part of writing a tree.  Implementation detail.  I don't care.  As long as the tree works for ONE data type, going to a template should make it work for ANY data type.  (1)

All the hard work went into actually making the tree.  Going to a template so it can use any data type, instead of just "myData" is easy.  Just say template<typename myData> so that you can use it with different types, instead of needing the typedef, which can only be one type.  Or, use "T" like everyone else:

```
template<typename T>
class tree {
private:
    template<typename T>
    struct node {
        T data;
        node<T> * left, right;
    };
    node<T> * head;
public:
    void add(T value);
    bool is_value_in_the_tree(const T &value);
};
```

Notice that since tree and node are now templates, you have to specify what the type is when you use them, although it can be different types for different trees.  tree would be a tree of strings.

```
tree<std::string> t;
assert(!t.is_value_in_the_tree("hello");
t.add("hello")
assert(t.is_value_in_the_tree("hello");
```

Also note that the nodes are private, and use the same T.  You don't have to make them private, but I would.  But making them use the same type is critical, because if someone declares tree the nodes will be handling sometype.

note 1: Okay, obviously a tree won't work with any type, but you will get a linker error if the type is missing something that is needed by the tree, like operator<() or certain node constructors, depending on how the tree is implemented.

Comment: -1:A tree does not hold *sorted* data (but plain data, without compare). Read wikipage on [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29)s & [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)s

Comment: Also, a tree does not need to hold any internal data. Sometimes, the *shape* of the tree is the data itself.

Comment: I was trying to convey the idea that generalizing a datatype requires having a datatype to generalize.  Edited.